# jeditable(inline editor) is not working for dynamically generated elements

Tags: jquery, jeditable

Code for generating dynamic elements:

```
$(".add_entry").click(function(event) {
    id=event.target.id;
    var parent_id=($("#"+id+"").parent().get(0).id);
    var i=$("#"+parent_id+"_add").children().children().length;
    i=i+1;
    var content='<li id="'+parent_id+'_'+i+'"><div class="timelineUnit"><h4 class="click"        style="float:left;">Manager</h4><h4 style="float:right;"><span class="timelineDate   click">2010 - Present</span></h4><h5 class="click" style="clear:both;">Ligula Non Lectus</h5><p class="autogrow">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingVivamus sit amet ligula non lectus cursus egestas. Cras erat lorem, fringilla quis sagittis in, sagittis inNam leo tortor Nam leo tortor Vivamus.</p></div></li>';
    $("#"+parent_id+"_add").append(content);
});
```

and **jeditable function code**

```
$(function() {
    $(".click").editable("<?php echo HTTP_URL; ?>inline/php/assign.php", { 
        indicator : "<img src='<?php echo HTTP_URL; ?>inline/img/indicator.gif'>",
        tooltip   : "Click to edit...",
        style  : "inherit",
        submit    : 'Ok',
        cancel    : 'Cancel',
    });
});
```

The above code working well for html like 
    `<span class="click" id="name2">test</span>`
but not working for dynamically generated html form jquery(above function).

Answer (score 1):

For dynamically generated elements, the editable script also have to be called inside the generation script.

Replace your code as such :

```
    $(".add_entry").click(function(event) {
     id=event.target.id;
     var parent_id=($("#"+id+"").parent().get(0).id);
     var i=$("#"+parent_id+"_add").children().children().length;
     i=i+1;
     var content='<li id="'+parent_id+'_'+i+'"><div class="timelineUnit"><h4   class="click"        style="float:left;">Manager</h4><h4 style="float:right;"><span class="timelineDate   click">2010 - Present</span></h4><h5 class="click" style="clear:both;">Ligula Non Lectus</h5><p class="autogrow">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingVivamus sit amet ligula non lectus cursus egestas. Cras erat lorem, fringilla quis sagittis in, sagittis inNam leo tortor Nam leo tortor Vivamus.</p></div></li>';
      $("#"+parent_id+"_add").append(content);


      $(".click").editable("<?php echo HTTP_URL; ?>inline/php/assign.php", { 
       indicator : "<img src='<?php echo HTTP_URL; ?>inline/img/indicator.gif'>",
       tooltip   : "Click to edit...",
       style  : "inherit",
       submit    : 'Ok',
       cancel    : 'Cancel',
      });



    });
```

Answer (score 0):

by no means a javascript guy, but do tinker around sometimes.

but dont you need to write it with .live or .on  if you are injecting html in the DOM?